# Why is par and le used in this statement; Is it a rule or something else

Tags: grammaire, sens, expressions, vocabulaire, usage

Elle le tient par la main. From duolingo. Croisière au coucher du soleil story.v

Answer (score 4):

*Elle **le** tient **par** la main* uses ***par*** because that's the [usual preposition after *tenir*](https://www.noslangues-ourlanguages.gc.ca/fr/le-rouleau-des-prepositions/tenir) in this context and uses ***le*** because the person she holds by hand is male. Otherwise, that would have been *Elle **la** tient par la main.*